# How to finish a function when conditions met?

Tags: javascript, function, return

Currently new to JS, and creating a wage calculator, I have 4 different conditions that can be met, lets say a1 a2 b1 b2, each condition has a different pay rate. When the hourly pay rate is selected and the hours worked is input, it simply multiplies the hours worked by the pay rate, and leaves a thank you message in a text box at the bottom. My problem is, the function doesn't stop at the condition it should, it goes through to the last if statement. Say a2 is the condition met, it will do that condition, but it wont stop, and continue through to the last if statement. I've tried adding a return code at the end of each if statement, but this stops the finish function from posting the thank you message. Any help appreciated, thankyou.

```
var intName;
var intHours = 0,
  intQualifyType, intAgeType;
var curWage = 0;
var blnContinue;
var strMessage = "";
var intNumCalc = 0;
var curTotal = 0;


function calcWage() {
    intName = (document.getElementById('txtName').value);
    intQualifyType = (document.getElementById('optQualifyType').value);
    intAgeType = (document.getElementById('optAgeType').value);
    intHours = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtHours').value);

    if (intQualifyType == "Code1" || intAgeType == "Years2") {
      curWage = intHours * 1;
    }
    alert(curWage);

    if (intQualifyType == "Code1" || intAgeType == "Years1") {
      curWage = intHours * 2;
    }

    document.getElementById('txtTotal').value = "$" + curWage.toFixed(2);
    curWage = parseFloat(curWage);
    intNumCalc++;

    blnContinue = confirm("Do you have another quote to process");

    if (blnContinue) {
      clearall();
    } else {
      finishUp();
    }


  } //end of calwage

function clearall() {
    document.getElementById('txtName').value = "";
    document.getElementById('txtHours').value = "";
    document.getElementById('msgInvest').value = "";
    document.getElementById('txtTotal').value = "";
    document.getElementById('txtName').focus();

  } // end of clearall

function finishUp() {
    strMessage = "Thank you for using our new Wage Calculator " + intName + "! ";
    strMessage = strMessage + "For your hours this week you are currently owed $" + curWage.toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById('msgFinish').value = strMessage;
    intNumCalc = 0
    curTotal = 0;
  } //end of finishUp
```

Comment: What does the inputs look like?

Comment: <select type="text" id="optQualifyType">
      <option selected="selected" value="Code1">Yes</option>
      <option value="Code2">No</option>
      
      </select>
<br /><br />

Are you of the age of 18 or older?

<select type="text" id="optAgeType">
      <option selected="selected" value="Years1">Yes</option>
      <option value="Years2">No</option>
      
      </select>
<br /><br />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dave Norm has a point, if that is the function your are trying to do.

This code will accept **2** possible **ANSWERS** for each condition as **TRUE**, since you're using **||** OR operator.

```
if (intQualifyType == "Code1" || intAgeType == "Years2") {
 curWage = intHours * 1;
}

alert(curWage);

if (intQualifyType == "Code1" || intAgeType == "Years1") {
  curWage = intHours * 2;
}
```

I also guest you need to use **&&** AND operator for your process.

You can **combine** the **2** statements as **1**. Like:

```
if(intQualifyType == "Code1" && intAgeType == "Years2") {
  curWage = intHours * 1;
}else if(intQualifyType == "Code1" && intAgeType == "Years1") {
  curWage = intHours * 2;
}

alert(curWage);
```

And maybe you need to add:

```
return false;
```

If you want to **terminate** the process after getting the right condition.

Comment: you and @Dave Norm were right, just had to fiddle with some other coding i had wrong, but your method worked. It's all working perfectly now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is here :

```
if(intQualifyType=="Code1" || intAgeType=="Years1")
```

and

```
if(intQualifyType=="Code1" || intAgeType=="Years2")
```

both will be run through as you are using an "or" logic gate. So both expressions are asking is the intQualifyType equal to Code1. 
  I think what you are looking for is an "and" logic gate something like:

```
if(intQualifyType=="Code1" && intAgeType=="Years2")
// some more stuff here
if(intQualifyType=="Code1" && intAgeType=="Years2")
```

Comment: Tried this with no luck